# Can Siri's voice be used to read selected text on iOS?

Tags: ios, siri

I've enabled the feature that allows reading out loud of selected text, however whenever I chose Siri original voice (I'm using Siri British female) iOS seems to ignore this and always tries to read using system default language (which is not English in my case).

When I switch to non Siri voice, like Serena for example, it works properly and English text is red correctly by Serena. But as soon as I switch to Siri voice iOS tries to read English text using other non-English and non-Siri voice.

Is this a bug or indeed Siri's voice can not be used for reading text?

Comment: It may be worth clarifying where within Settings you're making these changes? Multiple locations offer voice configurations, so it'd be good to know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I'm referring to settings under "Accessibility -> Speech" and "Accessibility -> Speech -> Voices"